# MVC 5 attachment View/Download functionality

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This may seem obvious but I'm having a hard time finding the answer.

I have a List of file paths which are stored as relative file paths.
("~\Data\1f492f55-c7ad-44ae-8cbc-93885ac4383a.jpg")
These files can be jpgs,docs or PDFs.
How can I give a View functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the below solution.This support any file types.

```
    public FileResult Download(int id)
    {
        var filePath = @"~\\Data\0e383d46-021d-48b4-9f03-e9a70bc894f7.jpg";
        //var filePath = @"~\\Data\\file.pdf";
        //var filePath = @"~\\Data\\word.docx";
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(careTakerFile.FilePath);
        return File(filePath, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593(v=vs.118).aspx) method to render content of a file (PDF /JPG etc..)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var filePath = @"C:\\temp\tempFile.pdf";
    return File(filePath, "application-pdf", "YourFriendlyFileName.pdf");
}
```

You may change the code the get the file paths and replace it with the hardcoded file path above.

Answer (score 0):

Upload them to the application and use relative path.
As localhost:80/images/image1.jpg